# how to solve .venv envoirnment MySQLdb error in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python and am experiencing an error "Module Not Found Error: no module named 'flask_mysqldb' ". I am using Linux Mint and the Python version is 3.10.

I've tried a lot of things like"sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade", various Pip commands.